# Desktop icons settings reset at every boot

Tags: unity, 13.04, icons, desktop-icons

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04, and I'm having problems with the desktop icons: after every boot desktop icon setting are reset and "computer", Home Folder and Trash icons are shown on the desktop. If I open Ubuntu Tweak and try to change settings, they are ignored; doing a logout/login results in some cases in the correct settings being applied, but after a reboot, everything is back to the initial default settings.

I tried resetting both Unity and Compiz, I tried changing setting with gnome-tweak-tool, but nothing fixed this issue. Any idea of what might be wrong?